# How to restore quantity on product cancel in opencart 2

Tags: opencart2.x

I am new to `opencart`. I have placed an order but when I am canceling it then the quantity is not restored back to inventory system

How can I restore the qty when it is canceled

Comment: Not really on-topic here IMO. Best asked at Opencart's support resources (or maybe it already has a Stack Exchange site)

Comment: in opencart if your order is in complete state (defined by u in admin setting) then opencart will decrease quantity from stock else it will not. So if your order in complete state why you are canceling it ? or just don't update order state to complete. Currently there is no way you can restore quantity in OC, there return management also don't do it (just for feel no real coding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link , the order has to be deleted.
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/786